# How to validate my reactive form using dynamic buttons?

Tags: angular, validation

Im using dynamic buttons in angular reactive forms. Im trying to use validators so that buttons get hidden or change when the input is null or invalid. so far I could hide button, change edit to save when the input is not null. but when its not valid it still saves and i dont want that.

I have a detailsComponent that my form is in it. i use *ngSwitchCase and a directive for editing. another component is buttonsComponent which basically include the loop of buttons and attributes of hidden and disable. my main logic is in app.component.

this is part of my app.component:

```
 buttons: ButtonDef[] = [
    { label: 'Edit', iconClass: 'fa-pen-square',
      callbackFn: x => {
        this.editMode = true;
      },
      visibleFn: x => !this.editMode,
      enabledFn: x => x.canEdit,

    },
    { label: 'Save', iconClass: 'fa-check-square',
      callbackFn: x => {
        // console.log('Save pressed', x);
        this.editMode = false;
        this.hasChanges = false;
        const updated: Update<Document> = {
          id: x.id,
          changes: this.details.getUpdatedValues()
        };
        this.store.dispatch(new DocumentActions.Save(updated));
      },
      visibleFn: x => this.editMode,
      enabledFn: x => this.hasChanges
    },
    { label: 'Cancle', iconClass: 'fa-undo',
      callbackFn: x => {
        // console.log('Reset pressed', x);
        this.editMode = false;
      },
      visibleFn: x => this.editMode
    }
  ];

  editMode: boolean;
  hasChanges = false;

  constructor(private readonly store: Store<any>, private readonly api: 
  AppService) {
    this.documents$ = api.getAllDocuments();
  }

  onValueUpdated(event: boolean) {
    this.hasChanges = event;
    this.btns.update();
  }

  onSelectedId(event: string) {
    // console.log(event);
    if (event) {
      this.document$ = 
      this.store.pipe(select(DocumentSelectors.getById(event)));
      this.store.dispatch(new DocumentActions.Load(event));
    }
  }
```

I want to have my Save button disable until the required field is written.

Comment: here is my github link for all code: https://github.com/parak80/reactiveFormsValidation